# How to send pdf file to a specific whatsApp number using React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, pdf, whatsapp

I want to send a pdf file created by expo-print library to a specific whatsApp number. I know there are libraries such as expo-sharing that can share a pdf to whatsApp but I want to open a specific number on WhatsApp even if its not in my contacts. I have been doing this.

```
const file = await printToFileAsync({
      html: invoiceHtml,
      base64:false
    });
    const pdfName = `${file.uri.slice(
      0,
      file.uri.lastIndexOf('/') + 1
    )}invoice.pdf`;
    await FileSystem.moveAsync({
      from: file.uri,
      to: pdfName,
    });

let url = 'whatsapp://send?phone=92' + customerNumber.toString().substring(1) + '&file=' + pdfName;
    Linking.canOpenURL(url)
      .then((supported) => {
        if (supported) {
          return Linking.openURL(url);
        } else {
          throw new Error('WhatsApp is not installed on your device');
        }
      })
      .then((data) => {
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert(error.message);
      });
```

It is opening the conversation but the file I specify is not there. expo-print is also generating the pdf, I checked.